# Android Studio app crashes

Tags: java, android, crash

I have a problem with my application I am making on Android Studio. I don't know why, but after the splash screen, the application crashes. I want the activity "Accueil" to open after the splash screen. It worked fine last week and now it doesn't anymore. I didn't touch anything. I show you the manifest, and the `.java` files.

Splashscreen.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Splashscreen extends Activity {
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    }

    Thread splashTread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
        StartAnimations();
        Thread loading = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                    Intent main = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,Menu.class);
                    startActivity(main);
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        loading.start();
    }

    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        anim.reset();
        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
        l.clearAnimation();
        l.startAnimation(anim);
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);
        splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;

                    while (waited < 3500) {
                        sleep(100);
                        waited += 100;
                    }

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,Menu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thibaudmangeot.erdfapplicationsecurite">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Accueil"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_accueil"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Accueil.java:

```
package com.example.thibaudmangeot.erdfapplicationsecurite;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

public class Accueil extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accueil);

        Button buttonfis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonfis);

        buttonfis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goTosignin();
            }
        });
    }

    private void goTosignin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put your crash log.

Comment: Also don't put UI thread on sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
Intent main = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, Accueil.class);
                    startActivity(main);
                     finish();
```

Instead of

```
Intent main = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, Menu.class);
                startActivity(main);
                finish();
```

You have not even mentioned Menu activity in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

This is your error:

```
Intent main = new   Intent(Splashscreen.this,Menu.class);
```

it should be:

```
Intent main = new   Intent(Splashscreen.this, Accueil.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your application is crashing maybe because of two reasons

1. There is no Activity named "Menu"
2. Menu Activity is not mentioned in manifest file

If you want to open "Accueil" activity then write your intent in following fashion.

```
Intent openAccueil = new   Intent(Splashscreen.this,Menu.class);
startActivity(openAccueil);
```